# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in kendo mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

My layout page code is below-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon"   href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Images/favicon.ico")""/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title </title>

  @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar " style="background-color: white; border: none;">
            </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #01A9DB; border: none;">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                   </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
           @RenderSection("HeadContent",required:false)
    <div class="container">
        <div style="margin: 0% 1% 0% 1%;">
            @RenderBody()

        </div>

        <hr />
    </div>
    <footer>
        </footer>
</div>
 @RenderSection("scripts",required:false)

</body>
</html>
```

And i have error on chart page 
Chart.cshtml page

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
    .Name("chart")
    .Title("Site Visitors Stats \n /thousands/")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .Series(series => {
        series.Bar(new double[] { 56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 138000 }).Name("Total Visits");
        series.Bar(new double[] { 52000, 34000, 23000, 48000, 67000, 83000 }).Name("Unique visitors");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .Max(140000)
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
) 
</div>
```

when i run the project - output is blank view no chart on the page ,
when i see in the console i found the error below

[image]

please help me.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ ?

Comment: Hahah.. I found the solution.. i am using mvc4 with kendo ui latest version and that needs jquery version 1.9.1 file , and i am using old jquery file 1.7.1 just i add new jquery file and    done......